# Working with subdirs with qmake

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, qmake

Hello I want to do something like this in my project

```
project/
--sources/ -- cpp, h
--forms/ -- ui
--build/ -- object files, mocs
--bin/ -- execute file will appear here
--scripts/ -- this folder should be copied in the bin/ folder after make
project.pro - pro-file
```

I use qtcreator, but I find nothing like this stuff. So I've tried to write *.pro file myself. Now I have something like

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = project
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += src/main.cpp\
        src/mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += src/mainwindow.h

FORMS    += src/mainwindow.ui
```

But this is not enough. So I'm asking for help.

UPD: Also, there is some stuff for build dir in .pro.user, but I think it's wrong way.

Comment: to place your executable add the line: DESTDIR= bin

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem is in moving dir scripts/ into bin/. Make can do this, but I don't really know about qmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your file. This does everything you need. I listed two methods of copying the scripts to the bin directory. Credit for the second method goes to **jwernerny**. Ask if you have any questions.

```
DESTDIR= ./bin          #adds the exe to bin
MOC_DIR = ./build       # Deals with MOCS
OBJECTS_DIR = ./build   #deals with objects
```

#Two Methods for Copying the scripts over.

```
dist.commands += cp -r ./scrpits ./bin
```

## OR

```
script_install.path = ./build
script_install.files = ./scripts/*
INSTALLS += script_install
```

Comment: This may work on systems that have 'cp'.  $$QMAKE_COPY or $$QMAKE_COPY_DIR (defined in qmake.conf for the current QMAKESPEC) would be more transportable.  The other solution is using INSTALLS.

Answer (score 3):

I think [qmake INSTALLS](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs) provides a good, cross platform solution to the problem without relying on specific commands (i.e. cp) being available on the system.  It only requires running `make install`.

```
script_install.path = ./build
script_install.files = ./scripts/*
INSTALLS += script_install
```